# Ajax UpdateTargedId / Browser doesn't refresh ASP MVC Partial View

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I Have HTML Page "Index.cshtml"

```
<div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="employeeList">
@Html.Partial("IndexPartial");  
        </div>
        <div id="second">
           other div
        </div>
        <button onclick="Increase()">increase</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

partial view which contains employee table, button which clicked calls JS Script which executes controller method increasing employee age

```
<script>
    function Increase(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Main/Increase',
            data: { id: 5 },
            UpdateTargetId:"employeeList",
            success: function () {
                alert('Added');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I ran firebug and it shows that each button click returns html response with updated employee Table (employee age is updated) but in browser there are still old values until I manually refresh page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem a bit confused. Let's go over a few things.

[Partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402902%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is a built-in method that renders a view to a string (an IHtmlString). This runs once when the page is being constructed.

`$.ajax()` is a jQuery function. This function (as far as I can recall) does not accept a property called `UpdateTargetId`. I think you've confused that with the .NET [AjaxOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) class which **does** accept an option called *UpdateTargetId*.

One way to quickly get things working is to change your success function to take a `data` argument and then insert the HTML into the div.

```
success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) { }
```